# There's no line here to end. \end{frame}

Tags: beamer, errors

when i compile my beamer , it says that `There's no line here to end. \end{frame}`  what does that mean? But the strange is when i delete the `\\~` after every `\item` , it works right. But i want to start every item in every other line. who can explain the reason of error? And are there any other ways to start every item in every other line? thanks

Comment: use of `\\ ` outside a tabular or math alignment is almost always wrong. If you want to start a new paragraph just leave a blank line in the source.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle;you've mistaken me, i want to start every other line. Leaving a blank just start from a newline

Comment: It inserts a vertical space `\parskip` (which may be set to 0pt, or not, depending) `\\\mbox{}` probably makes a blank line and stops the warning, but it is always the wrong markup.

Comment: Please, make a minimal example

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can modify the `\itemsep` length within the itemize environment but you better listen David Carlisle's advice. `\\` is almost always does the wrong thing while you might have the innocent *skip a line please*. In a list, there is no next line but spacing between items. You can choose what that space should look like for your own taste but be aware that this is a habit introduced by Powerpoint.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}    
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}\itemsep=3ex
    \item One item
    \item Two items
    \item Three items
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]